# Add a glow effect around the Earth

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I created this earth using cycles can anybody tell me how to add a ***glow effects*** to it and also if **anything** could be done to make it better.
[image: The Earth]

Comment: Welcome to this website. Please note that it is about questions only and that tutorial requests will not be well reviewed. I recommend that you try to achieve your goal first, and then ask about a specific part which is causing trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot actually this is my first time on any forum

Comment: That's okay; but, what have you tried? What render engine are you using? If you haven't already, try a mix of volume scatter and emission shades, in case you are using Cycles. I can't really help you with BI, though...

Comment: I used cycles !!

Comment: sorry, it wasn't it the tags, and I seem to have missed it.

Comment: Also why cant i use a cloud map no i edited it. its k

Comment: Just use the compositor to make it glow.

Comment: How @Vince Scalia

Comment: @Shaiq what do you mean? You should be able to; how did you try to use it, exactly?

Comment: I used transparent with diffuse in a mix node and put it into factor

Comment: Wait, everyone slow down. I got this one.

Comment: Can i add a .blend file. I am really getting curios for the next comment (this is awesome)

Comment: No I'm just a-goin to answer.

Comment: have you seen Andrew Prices's tutorial? http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-a-realistic-earth/

Comment: that's in blender internal i want it in cycles

Comment: @Shaiq Some of the same methods still apply, like adding another sphere, scaling it slightly larger, and adding a material to it using the cloud image as the factor for color and transparency. Between that and the glow, you should be able to figure something out.

Comment: yes i did that but it remained as it was ill try it again

Comment: Since the original question was about clouds you can get cloud images here http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=57747 and use those on a separate sphere that is slightly larger than the earth.

Comment: I find it odd that this question is marked as off-topic but the similarly vague black whole question is fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I just learned this myself, so @NoviceInDisguise can edit it if needed.*

### 1

Create a bright point of light in your scene. This would be planet earth- already created in your case. Glare can't happen without a target.

Render the image.

[image]

### 2

At the top of your screen, change the *screen layout* mode to be compositing. Once done, you may need to check a little box in the node editor that says **use nodes**.

[image]

### 3

Add a *glare* filter between the image input and the finished output. Optionally you may add a viewer node at the end of the string so you can see the image in the node editor. In order for a viewer node to be active, you need to check **Backdrop**. It's located near **use nodes**.

Set the glare mode to *fog glow*.

[image]

### 4

Mess with the settings on the glare node until you have a perfectly glowing planet.

Comment: And all this time I thought the earth was round! :(

Comment: Sorry but i tried that with my scene Vince do you think that using a pass index will help.

Comment: @Shaiq did it not work?

Comment: @VinceScalia i'll try it once more and then comment

Comment: @cegaton http://i.stack.imgur.com/aLcaP.png happy?

Comment: No i am sorry it didnt

Comment: what do you mean it didn't? may you post a .blend! it's foolproof!

Comment: Use http://pasteall.org/ to make a link.

Comment: Vince plz move this to chat

Comment: You don't have enough rep to chat. hang on. :P

Comment: yay it worked thanks alot i played around with the settings abit and it worked pretty much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20431/discussion-between-vince-scalia-and-shaiq).